# Numpy array integer / float division

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I found the following behaviour in Python/NumPy somewhat strange:

```py
In [51]: a = np.arange(10, 20)
In [52]: a = a / 10.0
In [53]: a
Out[53]: array([ 1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9])

In [54]: a = np.arange(10, 20)
In [55]: a /= 10.0
In [56]: a
Out[56]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I felt that `a=a/10.0` and `a/=10.0` should return the same result. Is this intended and documented somewhere?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem with `a /= 10.0` is that it modifies the array in place, and it won't change the the dtype of the array, so all the floats are converted to integers. On the other hand `a = a / 10.0` created a new array, and the type can be changed if a new array is being created.

From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays):

> Note that assignments may result in changes if assigning higher types
>   to lower types (like floats to ints) or even exceptions (assigning
>   complex to floats or ints):

Comment: +1 for the great answer. Personally, when I tried to generate double floats, I always used np.arange(10., 20.) to be safe.